# Differential equation of function composition of two variables.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system I am completely stuck on.
$$\dfrac{\left[A×\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}-B×\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}+C_1\right]}{\ln\left[\dfrac{B×\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}-x+y}{A×\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}-x+y}\right]}=D×\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}=E×\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}+C_2$$

Differential equation of function composition of two variables.

I need to find a numerical solution of this system, like $f(x(t),y(t)) =...$

Comment: It looks like you have a system of differential equations, but the "two variables" $x,y$ are actually functions of (time) $t$.  I'm not sure what you mean by "function composition".  Are there initial conditions to go along with this system?  Are you concerned to provide the solution as an "autonomous" system (no explicit dependence of terms on $t$)?

Comment: Substituting x for y would give something like $a\dot y+b=\dot y\ln\left(\frac{c\dot y+dy+e}{f\dot y+gy+h}\right)$ and frankly I still don't know what to make of it ?